# Is this code slowing down (or contains additional unwanted inputs?) - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I've been taking part in Programming Competition and it's my first time. And now I'm aware that the system checks the code for errors. One particular question is really making me sweat. I've been on it for 2 hours now and the competition system is saying that my code is not correct. The question says that there's a jury program that inputs different values to my code and reads from console. Here's the question:

> `This is interactive problem. Your program will interact with jury’s program using standard input and standard output. The jury’s program has chosen a number from 1 to n, and your program must guess it. In order to do it, your program must print its guesses to the jury’s program, and it would respond whether the chosen number is greater, less, or equal to the guess. It is known that 1 ≤ n ≤ 10^9. Your program must make at most 30 guesses.`

### Interaction Protocol

First, your program must read n from standard input. After that the interaction goes as follows: your
program must print its guess to standard output and then read the jury’s program response from standard
input.
The following responses are possible:

• “1” — the chosen number is greater than the last guess;

• “-1” — the chosen number is less than the last guess;

• “0” — the last guess is correct. After reading 0 your program must terminate.

---

And here's my *working* and *tested* code which gave me the correct (IMO) answer:

```
low = 1
high = int(input())
while True:
    guess = (high + low)//2
    print(guess)
    a = int(input())
    if a == 0:
        break
    elif a == 1:
        low = guess
    elif a == -1:
        high = guess
```

Instead of taking it and running, it said *it is waiting for the input* as I understood - "Idleness Limit Exceeded" is the issue. But it worked when I tested it on the various local machines. I hope one of you kind strangers can help me and point out where I made mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Badly indented python code is invalid python code. Please ensure the indentation of the code blocks in your question is as you expect it. In this case, check your `while` loop.

Comment: Also, we cannot tell you why your code is timing out while waiting for input without seeing the other code that sends the input your code expects (and you obviously don't have access to this code). Maybe they want you to use `sys.stdin` instead of input()?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi no, not sys.stdin. Jury's program responses from _standart input_. But thanks for responding and trying to help

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I fixed it. I don't know how I did, I just tweaked around with the code tried that out:

```
low = 1
high = int(input())
while True:
guess = (high + low)//2
print(guess)
a = int(input())
if a == 0:
    break
elif a == 1:
    low = guess + 1
elif a == -1:
    high = guess - 1
```

And surprisingly, it worked :D